# Non flat base change

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m},k,E)$ be a Noetherian local ring with $E$ an injective hull of $k$, let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module and $M^{\vee}=\mathrm{Hom}_{R}(M,E)$. Is there a non flat $R$-algebra $S$ such that $R\to k\cong F\to S$ where $F$ is a field and $$S\otimes _{R}\mathrm{Tor}_{*}^{R}(M,M^{\vee}\oplus E)\cong \mathrm{Tor}_{*}^{R}(M,S\otimes_{R}(M^{\vee}\oplus E))\ ?$$

I have been studing how to use a flatness criterion of Bhatt, Iyengar and Ma in order to prove the generalized Auslander-Reiten conjecture. The hypothesis that $S$ is flat guarantees that $$S\otimes _{R}\mathrm{Tor}_{*}^{R}(M,M^{\vee}\oplus E)\cong \mathrm{Tor}_{*}^{R}(M,S\otimes_{R}(M^{\vee}\oplus E))$$ but also implies that $R$ is regular, in that case, this problem seems to be simple by the work of Auslander et al. Then, the other possibility is try to find a non flat algebra $S$ such that $R\to k\cong F\to S$ and $$S\otimes _{R}\mathrm{Tor}_{*}^{R}(M,M^{\vee}\oplus E)\cong \mathrm{Tor}_{*}^{R}(M,S\otimes_{R}(M^{\vee}\oplus E)),$$ but I don't know if such a thing is possible.